# Loop into Register variables in Ansible Playbook to generate json payloads

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

actually i develop an ansible playbook, i need to loop into registred variable to generate payload json using template to send it later through an API

My task :

```
- name: check bad directories permissions
  shell: /tmp/check_permission.sh -d
  register: dir_output
- name : plugin output
  debug:
    msg: "{{dir_output}}"
```

results of debug :

```
ok: [hostname1] => {}
MSG:

 {'changed': True, 'end': '2022-07-21 12:37:10.039682', 'stdout': 'OK : No folders with      wrong permissions\n\n0', 'cmd': '/tmp/check_permission.sh -d', 'failed': True, 'delta': '0:00:00.759062', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 1, 'start': '2022-07-21 12:37:09.280620', 'msg': 'non-zero return code', 'stdout_lines': ['OK : No folders with wrong permissions', '', '0'], 'stderr_lines': []}


 ok: [hostname2] => {}

MSG:

{'changed': True, 'end': '2022-07-21 12:37:07.263145', 'stdout': 'OK : No folders with wrong permissions\n\n0', 'cmd': '/tmp/check_permission.sh -d', 'failed': True, 'delta': '0:00:00.396584', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 1, 'start': '2022-07-21 12:37:06.866561', 'msg': 'non-zero return code', 'stdout_lines': ['OK : No folders with wrong permissions', '', '0'], 'stderr_lines': []}
```

My Loop :

```
  name: Generating json paylod
  template:
    src: "check_template3.json.j2"
    dest: "/tmp/check_template3.json"
  loop:
  - "{{dir_output}}"
  run_once: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  tags: render exit_status
```

my template :

```
    {

     results: "{{item}}"

      }
```

My .json results :

```
    {

results: "{'changed': True, 'end': '2022-07-21 12:37:10.039682', 'stdout': 'OK : No folders with wrong permissions\n\n0', 'cmd': '/tmp/check_permission.sh -d', 'failed': True, 'delta': '0:00:00.759062', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 1, 'start': '2022-07-21 12:37:09.280620', 'msg': 'non-zero return code', 'stdout_lines': ['OK : No folders with wrong permissions', '', '0'], 'stderr_lines': []}"

}
```

expected results :

i need to loop on register and see two output messages on my json

```
    {

results: "{'changed': True, 'end': '2022-07-21 12:37:10.039682', 'stdout': 'OK : No folders with wrong permissions\n\n0', 'cmd': '/tmp/check_permission.sh -d', 'failed': True, 'delta': '0:00:00.759062', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 1, 'start': '2022-07-21 12:37:09.280620', 'msg': 'non-zero return code', 'stdout_lines': ['OK : No folders with wrong permissions', '', '0'], 'stderr_lines': []}"

results: "second results of the second hostname"

}
```

Any idea, thanks

Comment: The expected result is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: content
      vars:
        content: |-
          {
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          results: {{ hostvars[host]['dir_output']|to_json }}
          {% endfor %}
          }
      run_once: true
```

The content is not a valid YAML/JSON.